# React Native - display a graphical representation of obtained marks, passing marks and total marks

Tags: react-native

I have to display the test summary for a user which has a graphical representation of marks obtained, passing marks and total marks - something similar to a speedometer as shown in below wireframe.
[image: Score Graph]

I checked that react-d3-speedometer comes quite close to this requirement. However it is not available for react native. Can you please suggest a suitable plug-in which will help me to display the test summary in graphical format?